# cmake add boost subproject

Tags: cmake, boost

I have recently migrated my project to cmake, and I struggle to build it with my boost dependency in a a subproject. boost is included in my .gitmodules file like this:

```
[submodule "boost"]
    path = dependencies/boost
    url = https://github.com/boostorg/boost
```

and in my CMakeFile I include it like this:

```
add_subdirectory(dependencies/boost)
```

However, when building, I get the following error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at dependencies/boost/CMakeLists.txt:20 (include):
[cmake]   include could not find requested file:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     BoostRoot
[cmake]
```

How do I correctly include a dependency in my parent CMakeFile? Which alternatives do you suggest? I would like to have the dependencies as git submodules, so please do not suggest alternatives to that, I would like to transition away from using the system packet manager for that.

Comment: Boost is built with b2, but do support cmake through this: https://github.com/boostorg/cmake

Comment: How do I pass cmake arguments to add_subdirectory? If I want to add DBOOST_ENABLE_MPI, how would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, usually I just use vcpkg + manifest to install boost and make it importable

Comment: Which boost libraries do you want to use? Submodules are okay when using boost header-only libraries. Otherwise you have to build boost yourself. This may take some time (up to hours, depending on your hardware), so submodules are no good choice.

Comment: I already built it, only took some minutes. I would like to have complete control over the dependencies, and that is something git submodules are well suited for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: Somehow, I forgot to recourse the submodules of boost itself